# How do i remove spaces after a specific character or seperator in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Example lines:

```
hi ho:hi ho 
bye no:bye no
hi bye no:hi bye no
```

and i want:

```
hi ho:hiho 
bye no:byeno 
hi bye no:hibyeno
```

so basically i want to remove all spaces after _
some lines also have multiple spaces after _

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no clue how to do this one, so i havent really tried anything other then searching on google/youtube ect for like 1 hour before posting here. Hopefully someone knows how this can be done :)

Comment: [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)

Comment: [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Which part should i be looking at? Cant really see anything there that i can use to get this done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution that does not need advanced Regex knowledge is just
to look for `:[word][space]` and replace it by `:[word]",
this removing all spaces that follow words after the colon.

Find what : `:(\w+)` 
Replace with : `:\1`

Do Replace All as many times as it still finds any blanks, for cases
where several blanks exist, like in "hi bye no:hi bye no".

This is not a sophisticated solution, on purpose, but I suggest studying
some of the links in the comments below your post, to better understand
Regex.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be possible to do the same thing with . and _ aswell by using that method? so instead of removing spaces after : it will remove . or _?

Comment: Yes, of course. Keep a backup in case of error where Undo won't work.

Comment: Hmm im only able to do _ and - .When i try Find what :  :(\w+).
Replace with:  :\1 it removes one char at the end of every line. So what should the find what look like to be able to only remove the .?